# MINI F7 (HD +OSD +VTX SWITCH)

Tags: quadcopters, flight-controller, dji, sbus

How does the switch in the MINI F7 (HD +OSD +VTX SWITCH) flight controller works?
I know that you have to connect to pads, but then how can you change, for example, from DJI system to a SBUS input?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 'VTX switch' means that you can switch the power to the VTX on and off, with the BetaFlight 'pit mode'. That could be useful if your VTX overheats when it's not flying. 'Pit mode' normally refers to an option in the VTX where it runs at very low power to avoid interfering with other pilots, but not all VTXs support it, so I guess cutting the power is a way for the FC to offer a similar feature.

There only appears to be one video-in pad, so I don't think it can be used to switch between cameras.

SBUS is a receiver protocol, not a video signal.